# The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7, windows-server-2008, asmx

Currently migrating a number of .NET 2.0/4.0 apps to Windows server 2008 r2, IIS7.5

One of the apps uses a web service (.asmx) but for some reason the server returns a 404 Not found and within the exception

***There was no endpoint listening at [http://servername/service.asmx] that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action***

I can navigate to the service url in the browser and see the list of web methods.  So I know the service is running and accessible.

The weird thing is we have a dev environment with exactly the same setup and is working fine.  I can also reference the service running on the production from the dev code and the app works as expected.

I have tried a load of the things mentioned on these sites but nothing seems to have resolved it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your iis may not be properly configured,is calling to services other than your server works.?

Comment: what do you mean? I am able to load .aspx, ascx files in both .NET 2 and .NET 4 application pools and I can navigate directly to the .asmx service both locally and remotely.  The service will not consume from within the same server.  i.e. I can consume the service from a different server running the same code etc